# Is it possible to create a self-referential struct on the stack instead of the heap using Pin?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to allocate self-referential structs on stack? The [pin](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#example-self-referential-struct) documentation shows an example of pinning a struct on the heap. I followed it to write corresponding code:

```
pub struct Cont {
    pub f: i32,
    // shall point to 'f' field
    ptr_f: NonNull<i32>,
}

impl Cont {
    pub fn read(&self) -> i32 {
        unsafe { *self.ptr_f.as_ref() }
    }

    pub fn pinned(value: i32) -> Pin<Self> {
        // ensures ptr_f = &f
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Cont::pinned(5);
    let b = Cont::pinned(12);

    assert_eq!(a.f, a.read());
    assert_eq!(b.f, b.read());
}
```

but I don't know how to write the `Cont::pinned` function, or even if it's the right signature (if even possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I don't know how to write the `Cont::pinned` function, or even if it's the right signature (if even possible).

The type parameter to `Pin<P>` is always a pointer or reference; a `Pin` never owns its data, except via an owning pointer type such as `Box`. Given that you want to keep the original value on the stack, the analogue of the function in the example is:

```
fn pinned(value: i32) -> Pin<&mut Self>;
```

But this isn't possible because a function can't return a reference to something it created - unless that something is stored on the heap or in static memory. So, if you were to construct a `Pin` of a stack-allocated value, you'd have to create the unpinned value first, so that that the pin can reference it.

Perhaps you might try to design an API that creates a `Pin` by mutating some data that is already on the stack:

```
let a: Option<Cont> = None;
let b: Option<Cont> = None;

let a = Cont::pinned(&mut a, 5);
let b = Cont::pinned(&mut b, 12);
```

But then the value would live longer than the pin and you can only enforce the pin guarantees while the pin is live, making this *unsound*.

To make it sound, you would need to somehow enforce that the original values cannot be accessed after the pin is dropped. This would result in a very constrained API. For example:

```
fn main() {
    // setup_conts creates the pinned Cont values and calls the closure 
    setup_conts(5, 12, |a: Pin<&mut Cont>, b: Pin<&mut Cont>| {
        // a and b can only be used inside this closure
    })
}
```

Comment: So, this means that a self-referential struct allocated on the heap should respect a two-time protocol : first, allocate, then, initialize. In this case, is Pin even required?

Comment: If you have a plain `Box<T>`, you can still move the inner value out of the box at any time. Pinning prevents this.

Comment: @Guillaume `Pin` is very rarely *required*, and it doesn't help in all situations involving self-referential structs. You might find [this recent URLO thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/leak-memory-for-garbage-collection/48943/6?u=trentj) enlightening. But in the specific case of pinning a self-referential struct on the stack, you can do it even without `unsafe`: [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=535c2714fa792d13e37f0ff2db09d65b).